# Missing Downloads folder icon in macOS Dock

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I have changed my account and Home folder name. Now the Downloads folder in the macOS Dock is not showing the folder icon, if I select display as stack. A question mark image is shown instead:

[image]

How to make the downloads icon re-appear?

By the way, if I change from display as stack to display as folder the folder icon appears back:

[image]

Comment: Try removing the icon manually from the Dock and re-adding it from its new location. Does everything work as expected?

Comment: Added as an answer below. Please accept the answer as the correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: A relevant question would be "How did you change your account name?" That might have some bearing on what happened and why (and if there might be any other issues.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should manually remove the icon from the Dock and re-add it from its location in the new user folder. That should fix it.